# free stack function errors normally, but not when setting breakpoint

Tags: c, stack, runtime-error, free, abort

I'm trying to create a stack using a dynamic array and I'm getting an error when I try to run the `DeleteStack()` function, however, if I set a breakpoint before the function and run the main program up till that point, then continue past it, it executes properly. Would someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and why I'm seeing this behavior?

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "dynamic_array_stack.h"

int main() {

    // create stack
    DynArrayStack *S = CreateStack();

    // fill stack
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        Push(S, i);

    // try pushing past capacity, no error (realloc's)
    Push(S, 42);

    // top of stack
    printf("Top of stack is %d\n", Top(S));

    // pop all elements of stack
    while (Top(S) != INT_MIN) {
        printf("%d\n", Pop(S));
    }

    // delete stack, check pointer again
    DeleteStack(S);

    return 0;
}
```

`dynamic_array_stack.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct dynarraystack {
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
} DynArrayStack;

DynArrayStack* CreateStack() {
    DynArrayStack* S = malloc(sizeof(DynArrayStack));
    if (!S) {
        printf("Error: Could not create stack.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    S->capacity = 1;
    S->top = -1;
    S->array = malloc(S->capacity * sizeof(int));
    if (!S->array) {
        printf("Error: could not create stack.\n");
        return NULL;
    }   
    return S;   
}

int isFullStack(DynArrayStack *S) {
    return (S->top == S->capacity-1);
}

void DoubleStack(DynArrayStack *S) {
    S->capacity *= 2;
    S->array = realloc(S->array, S->capacity);
}

void Push(DynArrayStack *S, int data) {
    if (isFullStack(S))
        DoubleStack(S);
    S->array[++S->top] = data;
}

int isEmptyStack(DynArrayStack *S) {
    return S->top == -1;
}

int Top(DynArrayStack *S) {
    if(isEmptyStack(S))
        return INT_MIN;
    return S->array[S->top];        
}

int Pop(DynArrayStack *S) {
    if (isEmptyStack(S)) {
        printf("Array is empty. Returning INT_MIN.\n");
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    return S->array[S->top--];
}

void DeleteStack(DynArrayStack *S) {
    if (S) {
        if (S->array)
            free(S->array);
        free(S);
        printf("Stack deleted.\n");
    }
}
```

edit: Actually it only does not error if I set two breakpoints, one before the `while` loop (so I step through it manually), and another before the `DeleteStack()` function. Still confused though.

Comment: For future reference, don't *define* functions (i.e. write function implementations) in header files, not unless you're fond of linker errors.

Comment: Also, have you checked that the [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) call doesn't fail? It can return `NULL` you know.

Comment: It is probably not *the* problem, but this line: `if (S->array)` is checking whether the `array` is `NULL`. But you never set it to be `NULL`.

Comment: `S->array = realloc(S->array, S->capacity);` --> `S->array = realloc(S->array, S->capacity * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Ah, kept glossing right over that, thank you.

Comment: As @JoachimPileborg points out, you need to store the result of `realloc()` in a temporary variable and test for NULL. Otherwise, you will create a memory leak.

Comment: Could someone explain why it appeared to work at all (until the deletion step at least) when I wasn't making the size of `realloc` big enough?

Comment: *Undefined behavior* - that's it. And you are doubling the size every time, so you are getting some spares...